# visual studio installation splash screen starts then goes away

Tags: visual-studio

I'm having two issues; of which, both are the same...

I have VS2013 Update 3.

When I try and start the Update 4 package, the splash screen starts, then immediately goes away.

I'm having a similar version with trying to install the initial version of VS2012 (since 2013 is incompatible with BizTalk unless I have BizTalk, Update 2).

I have tried everything I know and read everything I can on it. I have and  HP EliteBook Folio 9470m Ultrabook. I have updated the video driver; downloaded and saved the files to try and run from them; tried downloading and extracting ISO files from MSDN.

Nothing works!

Can somebody please help me be able to install versions of Visual Studio?

Note that I can install other software programs with no problem. It's just Visual Studio that is giving me the problem.

I can also download Nuget extensions and have them installed as well without any issues.

It's just the actual Visual Studio application download or Update version of that application that can't be started....

Answer (score 0):

I had to run the package by:

1. Mount the ISO image as a virtual DVD
2. Open the disk, right-click VS2013.4.exe, and "Run As Administrator".
3. Launch Task Manager and watch till the process was done.

The splash screen does either freeze or vanish, but the install is actually running in the background. In fact, I think that in one case it never completely exited (you will see more than one msiexec instance running), but in the end it did install. You can check the install log to be sure.

Comment: Thanks, but no luck... I don't see that background task running. My PC does not have a DVD drive, so I use 7-Zip to extract the ISO image to the hard drive and try the setup. but, like I said, no luck...